# htaccess url aliases on custom website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I'm developing a site with 5-6 pages like main.php(homepage), event.php(landing page of an event), article.php(another news landing page) etc etc etc...

I'm wondering how would it be possible to rewrite urls like "http://www.domain.com/event.php?eid=145" to something like "http://www.domain.com/event/title-of-event"

I've read a couple of articles on .htaccess but no luck yet currently I'm messing around with this but it's not what I want

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^event.php(.*)$ http://evented.localhost/event/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated or if you know of any decent url aliases tutorial for .htaccess.

Thnx.

EDIT:

This seems to work for event.php page it transforms a link into this http://domain.com/event/145 (according to the above example)

```
RewriteEngine on

#EVENT REWRITE

RewriteRule ^event/([^/\.]+)/?$ /event.php?eid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^event/(.*) /$1 [L]
```

How could I replace the event id with it's title ?

Comment: What's `title-of-event` value, the parameter value eid=`145`?

Comment: eid=145 is the id of the article in the database. On another column(events.eTitle) I have the title of the event. How would it be possible to replace 145 with the title and not worry about dublicate titles.It should work with event id but display the title instead.

Comment: In these cases is better to redirect to a php script. Reading the database cannot be done in .htacces files and the information is needed to complete the rewrite rule.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that, I was thinking to pass on the url the title as well and display the title but use the id would that work ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the initial URL with the title maps to a script that gets the correlation between the title and the ID of the target page, and redirects to that page. Which is the same I suggested in my previous comment. There is no way to redirect to the right page without the ID of the page, unless you replace the IDs with titles.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to.store the clean title with the other.data, then use the clean url to find the article.